# Heroku, hoe gem is not in gemlist, gemfile, gemfile.lock. Why is it trying to install it anyways?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to push to Heroku and it insists on trying to install a gem I do not have anywhere in my app.  I've have the latest changes committed to my git repo. The gem is hoe.  I've tried the version suggested in the error log with no luck.  It is not required for production so I decided to *try* to exclude it from the push.

Ok then Joe, it must be a dependency of another gem in .lock... Wrong, not there.

Ok then Joe, it must have something to do with rvm global gemset.  Even if it doesn't I deleted global and still no luck.

Output of push to heroku:

```
    Counting objects: 156, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (142/142), done.
Writing objects: 100% (156/156), 259.71 KiB | 158 KiB/s, done.
Total 156 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.0.3)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)
       Installing multi_json (1.6.1)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.12)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.12)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.5)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.1)
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.12)
       Installing mime-types (1.21)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.12)
       Installing mail (2.4.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.12)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.12)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.12)
       Installing net-ldap (0.3.1)
       Installing adauth (1.2.1)
       Installing sass (3.2.6)
       Installing bootstrap-sass (2.3.0.1)
       Installing carrierwave (0.8.0)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Installing json (1.7.7)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.1)
       Installing thor (0.17.0)
       Installing railties (3.2.12)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing commonjs (0.2.6)
       Installing formtastic (2.2.1)
       Installing formtastic-bootstrap (2.0.0)
       Installing hoe (3.5.0)
       Gem::InstallError: hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
       An error occurred while installing hoe (3.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install hoe -v '3.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:enigmatic-ravine-4893.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:enigmatic-ravine-4893.git'
```

My rubygems is good.  It must be heroku's that aren't (Wut?):

```
$ ~/Documents/workspace/archive $ gem -v
2.0.3
```

None of my gems require hoe:

```
$ ~/Documents/workspace/archive $ gem dependencies hoe --reverse-dependencies
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command dependencies
$ ~/Documents/workspace/archive $ gem dependency hoe --reverse-dependencies
No gems found matching hoe (>= 0)
```

Gemfile.lock (no mention of hoe):

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.0)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    adauth (1.2.1)
      net-ldap
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    carrierwave (0.8.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    commonjs (0.2.6)
    diff-lcs (1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    formtastic (2.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
    formtastic-bootstrap (2.1.1)
      formtastic (~> 2.2)
    hike (1.2.2)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.7)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    less (2.3.2)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.6)
    less-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.3.1)
    libv8 (3.11.8.17)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_request (0.2.3)
      rack-contrib
      railties
    mime-types (1.22)
    mini_portile (0.5.0)
    minitest (4.7.2)
    multi_json (1.7.2)
    net-ldap (0.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.5.9)
    pg (0.15.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    racc (1.4.9)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-contrib (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.11)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activerecord (= 3.2.11)
      activeresource (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.11)
    railties (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rake-compiler (0.8.3)
      rake
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.4)
    rexical (1.0.5)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    sass (3.2.7)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    therubyracer (0.11.4)
      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
      ref
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.3.7)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      execjs
      railties (>= 3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.0.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    validates_existence (0.8.0)
    webrat (0.7.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
    yaml_db (0.2.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  acts-as-taggable-on
  adauth (~> 1.2.1)
  bcrypt-ruby
  bootstrap-sass
  bundler (~> 1.3.5)
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  formtastic
  formtastic-bootstrap
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  less-rails
  meta_request
  mini_portile
  minitest
  pg
  racc
  rails (= 3.2.11)
  rake-compiler
  rdoc
  rexical
  rspec-rails (~> 2.0)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  therubyracer
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  validates_existence
  webrat
  yaml_db
```

Comment: what gem? some details? error log? something...

Comment: @NickGinanto, Thanks, added error to original question.  Where could I find a log with more info?

Comment: can you put your gemfile.lock too?

Comment: can you list the whole output of when you push to Heroku?

Comment: it's installing completely different versions of gems than your Gemfile.lock lists. Are you looking at the right Gemfile.lock?

Comment: That's a good point.  I just went extreme and cleared my git repo because I have different versions of that app in there.  Gonna try again.

Comment: what does `heroku version` give you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's help.  The problem was that My git repo had other versions of the app and one of those was used for the upload.  Thanks for pointing that out @sevenseacat.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first make sure you have an updated version of rubygems, for ruby 1.9.3 and up you should have v 2.0 and up of rubygems

if you have rubygems below 1.4 you seriously need to update

second, try this

```
gem dependency hoe --reverse-dependencies
```

to see what requires it

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't provide any additional info.